# Google calendar API ruby, datetime timezone

Tags: ruby, google-calendar-api

I have this code. which creates a event in my google calendar.

```
    client = Signet::OAuth2::Client.new(client_options)
    client.update!(session[:authorization])

    service = Google::Apis::CalendarV3::CalendarService.new
    service.authorization = client

    event = Google::Apis::CalendarV3::Event.new({
        start: Google::Apis::CalendarV3::EventDateTime.new(
            date_time: cf_event.starts_at.to_datetime.rfc3339,
            time_zone: 'America/Monterrey'
        ),
        end: Google::Apis::CalendarV3::EventDateTime.new(
            date_time: cf_event.ends_at.to_datetime.rfc3339,
            time_zone: 'America/Monterrey'  
        ),

        summary: cf_event.title
    })
```

It is a basic example my `cf_event` object has the `starts_at` attr, which is a timeWithZone.

so i had to do `cf_event.starts_at.to_datetime.rfc3339`.

Output 
    "2019-03-15T17:50:00+00:00"

The problem is, that the code creates, the event but with -6 hours.

If i go to google calendars my event it´s the day 15 at (11 - 11:50), and not (17 - 17:50)

what am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are inputting the time as `17:50:00` in `UTC+0` (the `+00:00` from your `date_time` stands for `UTC` or `UTC+0`), however, you specified a `time_zone` where you used Monterrey which follows the time zone `UTC-6`.

My guess here is that, your code takes `17:50:00` in `UTC+0` then converts it to Monterrey time zone `UTC-6` which results to `11:50:00`. Either try removing the `+00:00` or try making it `-06:00`.

Comment: I found the problem, the problem was that rails creates a record using UTC as default time zone. So I had to change, the default timezone. TY.